# Why is it declared that Jesus was fully God while on earth when he did not have all attributes of God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, gospel-of-john, hypostatic-union, glory

The common belief is that Jesus was fully God and fully man; that is, 100% God and 100% man.

In John 17:5, Jesus asks the Father to return his glory as he had before he became flesh. So, his glory was not limited, but taken away or relinquished. Therefore, Jesus lost an attribute of God. If you don't possess all attributes of what God is (e.g. possess 99% attributes), then you cannot claim to be fully God.

So my question to those who believe in the [hypostatic union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union#:%7E:text=The%20most%20basic%20explanation%20for%20the%20hypostatic%20union%20is%20Jesus%20Christ%20being%20both%20fully%20God%20and%20fully%20man.) of Christ: how is Jesus considered fully God during his earthly ministry when he declared that he doesn't have the glory of God?

Glory as an attribute of God - Exodus 16:10, 24:16-17, 33:18-19

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include from whom (i.e. denomination, etc.)  you would like an answer. Be aware that not everyone has "the common belief" that you mention.

Comment: This is potentially a good question, but as noted it isn't asked in the standard way that is expected for this site. As a general rule of thumb (i.e. it doesn't *always* work) you should word the question so that it could have a single correct answer, and that same answer could be given by a Catholic, a Baptist, or an Atheist.

Comment: This question is fully and thoroughly covered in Trinitarian doctrine, as expressed (by Athanasius in particular) at the Council of Nicea. I suggest it be scoped for this site as beliefs differ. It is a broad subject, highly important, and essential to an understanding of  the Son of God. Philippians 2:7 is, I suggest, crucial to the answer of this question.

Comment: @agarza Updated. Hopefully it's appropriate now.

Comment: "Therefore, Jesus lost an attribute of God" what is your framework that a) glory is an attribute, b) that Jesus lost it and c) that God can lack an attribute at all?

Answer (score 3):

Glory: (1) high renown or honor won by notable achievements. (2), magnificence or great beauty. Please notice what Jesus says at John 17:1, "Father, the hour has come; glorify Thy Son, that the Son may glorify Thee."

The request that Jesus makes at vs1 was that He be made known on earth that He might make God known to mankind. Here His request went beyond the earthy scene to heaven itself. His request involved nothing that was not His right.

He had "NOT" renounced deity. He had assumed humanity in behalf of God and for the sake of the world. He asked now for the return of His eternal manifestation, having completed His earthy revelation. Philippians 2:5-10 explains that His attributes were "veiled." In other words, He emptied Himself of the expression of deity, not the possession of deity.

This means at John 17:5 Jesus was praying for the full restoration of His eternal glory. He knew that this restoration was in the eternal plan of God; it was part of the joy set before Him as He faced the agony and shame of the cross. (Hebrews 12:2).

Comment: Up-voted +1, but I question the expression 'His eternal manifestation'. Surely 'manifestation' is the incarnation ? Therefore not 'eternal' (though His presence in humanity is certainly _prototokos_). But I certainly agree with 'He emptied himself of the expression of Deity, not the possession of Deity'. Yes, indeed.

Comment: Thanks Nigel. I corrected my mistake. I meant the word glory.

Comment: I agree with @NigelJ that saying "eternal manifestation" is questionable. It's also not common in theological literature and may confuse people. The eternal *Logos* is NOT a "manifestation". Jesus IS, but as NigelJ said the common term is "incarnation". Better say "bodily manifestation" of the *Logos*. Secondly, "eternal manifestation" may falsely imply that the body of the *Logos* exists "**from** eternity".  It should have been **for** eternity" (starting at conception).  I recommend saying "He asked now for the return of His **bodily** manifestation that exists **for eternity**, having ..."

Comment: I'm not sure this exactly answers the question: how is Jesus considered fully God during his earthly ministry when he declared that he doesn't have the glory of God?
So in other words, Jesus can lose "expression of deity" and still remain fully God? He can visually show that he's not God (expression) while still remaining God? Is "expression of deity" an attribute of God?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yes. I agree with all of that.

Comment: @O.J. Your are stating that 'glory is an _attribute_ of' . . .   deity. I am not so sure of that. Spirit, fulness and eternity are attributes of Deity, as such. (That is to say, not personal matters but matters of _nature_.) The Son of God did not lay aside his _integrity_ in becoming incarnate. But he did lay aside his glory.

Comment: @NigelJ How would you interpret 1 Corinthians 15:38-49 where it states that each type of body has its own glory? Does this not show that each body/kind has a specific (level of) glory as an attribute?

Comment: @O.J. Read the words of Jesus at John 17:5, notice He clearly says, "with the glory which I had with Thee before the world was." Since Jesus is God and therefore "eternal" He did "NOT" lay aside His nature which is deity. He laid aside His glory when He became human, I don't think His glory is an attribute. I base this on John 17:21-23 where Jesus prays (vs22) to share His glory with His disciples so they can become one just like Jesus and the Father are one in unity. AT John 10:30 Jesus and His Father are one in nature or essence. Here, Jesus prays for Him and the disciples be one in unity.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Which scripture would prove that glory is not an attribute? Which definition of glory are you using in your answer? And at v5, Jesus said he HAD glory; is this not possessive?

Comment: @O.J. If this is an exercise in disputing the hypostatic union, I regard it as a very weak argument indeed, involving technical discussion and definition as to 'glory'. Set against the massive evidence in scripture as a whole, I find it pointless to investigate this particular point . . . . .  myself. One could certainly not build a whole structure of doctrine based on this - extremely - weak foundation.

Comment: @NigelJ It's just a question to understand how can Jesus be fully God if he himself asserted that he was not equal with the Father, with the "glory" argument being one (of many) clear-cut example.

Comment: @O.J. How can a Son ever be not equal to a Father ? The begotten is ever equal (in life) to he that begets.

Comment: @O.J. Look, Jesus as the Son is equal to His Father in nature or essence. When the Son was sent into the world from heaven and became flesh/human being/a bond-servant per Philippians 2:5-8 He relinquished (for a time) the glory He already had in the first place. Notice at John 17:5 the first two words, "And now!" This indicates that Jesus finished His work on earth and prays for His disciples (vs22) to receive the same glory of being one in unity like Jesus and His Father. What your doing in logic is making a category error by equating being equal in nature to Jesus becoming a bond-servant.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Saying the Son is equal to His Father in nature/essence would be an assumption. Adam is the son of God, yet would we say that he is equal with God? Angels are labeled as sons of God, are they equal with God?

Comment: @NigelJ Will the saints who are begotten of God [1 Jo 5:18] be equal to God since they are begotten?

Comment: @O.J. They are 'partakers of the divine nature'. And they are 'the sons of God'. And 'it doth not yet appear what we shall be'. (But only if they be justified by faith, and that in the eyes of God almighty himself, who only is righteous.)

Answer (score 1):

Had Jesus presented himself in his Full Glory no one would be able to look upon him.  That would defeat the purpose of his presence as a man.  ( Remember Moses had to wear a veil not to scare people, because of the LIGHT of God’s glory emanating from his face from being near Him)!
If I leave something of mine with you for safekeeping, it does not mean I have lost it nor does it mean I don’t own it. I may ask you to return it to me since it is mine.
Jesus was doing this on a Spiritual level.